# Interfacing Arduino with Raspberry Pi

Tags: serial, sensor

Can we interface Arduino with Raspberry Pi?

I need to interface 16 pressure sensors with Arduino. And get the reading through to Raspberry Pi using serial port communication. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use serial communication between the Arduino and the Raspberry Pi.

According to the [Raspberry Pi docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md):

> By default, the UART transmit and receive pins are on GPIO 14 and GPIO 15 respectively, which are pins 8 and 10 on the GPIO header.

The same page indicates that the serial pins are used, by default, to communicate with the Raspberry Pi's console. You'll need to disable this (using `raspi-config` for example).

On the Arduino side of things, you will have to check the docs for your particular model to find the UART pins, normally labelled RX and TX.

Once that's done, you need to connect the Arduino's transmit pin (TX) to the Raspberry Pi's receive pin, and the Arduino's receive pin (RX) to the Raspberry Pi's transmit pin.

You can then transmit and receive data on the Raspberry Pi using whatever language or program you want. Python is a common choice: you can use a library like `pySerial`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

If you do a search for "raspberry pi arduino comms" you will find many potential solutions.

Note the correct spelling of Arduino.

If you have problems with your chosen solution then please post a new question detailing what you have done, what happens, and what you expected to happen.